# Updating a total from controls added using a list

Tags: jquery, html, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Apologies for the long post but I thought it best to include as much details as I could.

I have a question on how I can identify a change within an EditFor control such that I can use that value along with others to calculate a total. The main problem I'm having is that the EditFor controls are added from a list so are not fixed or have fixed IDs.

My view model looks like this:

```
public class LVNModel
{        
    public List<Street> Streets { get; set; }
}

public class Street
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public List<Properties> Houses { get; set; }
    public Int32 TotalPowerRed { get; set; }
    public Int32 TotalPowerYellow { get; set; }
    public Int32 TotalPowerBlue { get; set; }
}

public class Properties
{
    public Int32 Amps { get; set; }
    public String Phase { get; set; }
}
```

With my view code along the lines of:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title"></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body fixed-panel">
            @{var i = 0;}
            @foreach (var street in Model.Streets)
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.Label(street.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3 collapseheader", style = "text-align:left" })
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <a href="#" class="form-control textinputred" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseRed-@i" data-parent="#menu1" id="streetRed-@i">@Html.Label(street.TotalPowerRed.ToString())</a>
                        <div id="collapseRed-@(i++)" class="sublinks collapse">
                            @ShowRedHouses(street.Houses)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <a href="#" class="form-control textinputyellow" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseYellow-@i" data-parent="#menu1" id="streetYellow">@Html.Label(street.TotalPowerYellow.ToString())</a>
                        <div id="collapseYellow-@(i++)" class="sublinks collapse">
                            @ShowYellowHouses(street.Houses)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <a href="#" class="form-control textinputblue" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseBlue-@i" data-parent="#menu1" id="streetBlue">@Html.Label(street.TotalPowerBlue.ToString())</a>
                        <div id="collapseBlue-@(i++)" class="sublinks collapse">
                            @ShowBlueHouses(street.Houses)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I'm effectively processing each street and displaying a 3 collapsible controls by calling a different function for each. Each function (red shown below) then displays the details of the properties within each street:

```
@helper ShowRedHouses(List<Properties>
    street)
{
foreach (var property in street)
{
    if (property.Phase == "Red")
    {
            <a class="list-group-item small" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#prop" data-parent="#streetRed">
                <table>                    
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model1 => @property.Amps, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control textinputred", id = "redHouse" } })
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </a>
    }
}
}
```

This gives me the following display:

[Click here for screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4uYw.png)

So the area I'm having issues with is updating the totals i.e. Red 82 or street.TotalPowerRed when one of its sub-values (50 or 32 / @property.Amps) are changed.

There may be a completely different way of doing this but being new to MVC I just don't know where to start!

Comment: Its a bit unclear what your hoping to achieve with this. Your generating invalid html (duplicate `id` attributes) that have `name` attributes that have no relationship at all to your model and therefore can't be bound when you post back. But to answer your specific issue, you need to use class names

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes I realise at the moment that I have duplicate ids and this is probably the main issue I have as I'm not sure how you change these such that they are dynamic. So that when a new control is added it can easily be identified. I'll take a look at using class names if that will help.

Comment: What you really need to do is scrap all of this (especially the `@helper`) and start using view models and EditorTemplates to represent what you display and edit in a view and allow you to post back and bind to your model.